# Airflow signal Sigterm error when dags are scheduled

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, sigterm

I have airflow installed version 2.2.5 and made all the changes people have pointed out for solving the sigterm issue but still, I am facing the same issue. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I am myself answering this question as I got the solution for it. I didn't have enough points to comment on anyone else question. So to solve the Sigterm error, We have to make some changes in the airflow.cfg file. 
1) Increase KILLED_TASK_CLEANUP_TIME = 10000
2) Make sure DELETE_WORKER_PODS = False

Comment: If any of the above solutions don't work then you have to check for the multiple instances of your scheduler in your system. if there are multiple instances running then we have to kill the unused one. For that, if its a Linux machine then the code will be:-

Code is : ps -ef | grep python 

Then check for multiple scheduler instances and delete the unused one. You can rectify the unused one by its memory consumption, which will be 1 by default if it's not used then. Killing the duplicate instances will surely solve the problem.